# Ext.net Blocked frame with origin exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, frame, ext.net

When I try to open my page I am getting this exception (sometimes not always):

```
{success: false, message:"Blocked a frame with origin "my web site addres" from accessing a cross origin frame."}
```

I am using window. Can this be the reason for the exception?
Window basic properties;

```
<ext:Window runat="server" ID="winList" 
                    Hidden="True" Layout="VBoxLayout" Modal="True" AutoScroll="True" MinHeight="500"
                    MaxHeight="500" MinWidth="1270" MaxWidth="1270" X="20" Y="20" Closable="False">
                    <LayoutConfig>
                        <ext:VBoxLayoutConfig Align="Stretch" />
                    </LayoutConfig>
```

Comment: You're running into CORS, you can read more on that here: https://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Comment: @Zippy thank you for ur answer. But i dont get it clearly.
Actually i am new ext.net user . Can u explain ur answer? Thank you

Comment: You're getting that error when you want to display the window content from outside your web site. For example, when you run the app on your local machine and the window tries to load something from another server. In order to make it work, on your server you have to configure CORS to accept your local machine.

Comment: But i am getting this error on my local machine. I didnt use another server

Comment: The window tries to load some content from your web site address based on your error. ("Blocked a frame with origin "my web site addres"). Is "my web site addres" localhost?